# How to find avg value of two different arrays (Double and integer)

Tags: java, arrays, generics, java-8, average

I have to find avg value with this generic class
`code`

```
class Array <T> {
    private T[]array;
    
    public Array(T[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
    public T get (int index) {
        return array[index];
    }
    public int length() {
        return array.length;
    }
}
```

with this two arrays:

```
Array<Integer>set1 = new Array<>(new Integer[] {1 ,2 , 4, 5});

Array<Double>set2 = new Array<>(new Double[] {1.0 ,3.0, 5.0});
```

can some1 explain how it works?

Comment: What trouble are you having to sum the values and divide by the length of the array?

Comment: You can make sure `T extends Number` and then call `doubleValue()` on each element, sum them and then divide by the length. If you want the average to be of type `T` as well there is no generic way to achieve it (other than using reflection).

Comment: For unconstrained `T`s this is not possible because what is supposed to be the average of the `String`s `"this"` and `"that"`.

Comment: i actually tried to find avg of this two arrays with one cycle. I mean, create unique cycle to find avg of two arrays

Comment: <T extends Number> double sumOfList2(List<T> list1) {
        double s = 0.0;
smth like this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the definition of `Array` class should look like this in order to allow calculation of average values of the array elements:

```java
public class Array<T extends Number> {
// ...
}
```

Then the `avg` method may be implemented like this using Stream API:

```java
public double avg() {
    if (length() == 0) {
        return 0.0; // prevent NaN for empty array
    }
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .filter(Objects::isNotNull)
                 .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).sum() / length();
}
```

or use [`DoubleStream::average()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average())

```java
public double avg() {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
                 .filter(Objects::isNotNull)
                 .mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue) // DoubleStream
                 .average() // OptionalDouble
                 .orElse(0.0); // or .orElseGet(() -> 0.0)
}
```

Or plain loop may be used:

```java
public double avg() {
    if (length() == 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (T x : array) {
        sum += null == x ? 0.0 : x.doubleValue();
    }
    return sum / length();
}
```